# Having an issue installing IBM Cloud CLI on Windows 10

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services, ibm-cloud-tools, ibm-cloud-plugin

I am following the instructions to install IBM Cloud CLI on a Windows 10 virtual machine found here  https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/index.html#overview   and I am coming across this error on Step 1.  I am unsure why it is looking for a config.json file on my H drive and the ibm cloud install fails because of the error.  It also states "ibmcloud already installed" probably due to multiple attempts to install but they all fail.  I try to confirm the installation with "Ibmcloud dev help" after a reboot of the machine but get the same error.

Has anyone come across this?

Steps I am taking:

I am using a Windows 10 Enterprise virtual machine and I am an administrator.  I also ran PowerShell as an administrator.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted; iex(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://ibm.biz/idt-win-installer
')

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): A

[main] --==[ IBM Cloud Developer Tools - Installer for Windows, v1.2.0 ]==--
[install] Starting Installation/Update...
[install_deps] Checking for external dependency: git
[install_deps] Checking for external dependency: docker
[install_deps] Installing/updating external dependency: docker
[install_deps] Install/update completed for: docker
[install_deps] Checking for external dependency: kubectl
[install_deps] Checking for external dependency: helm
ibmcloud already installed
FAILED
Configuration error: open H:\.bluemix\plugins\config.json: The system cannot find the path specified.

[install_bx] IBM Cloud CLI version:
FAILED
Configuration error: open H:\.bluemix\plugins\config.json: The system cannot find the path specified.

[install_plugins] Installing/updating IBM Cloud CLI plugins used by IDT...
[install_plugins] Checking status of plugin: Cloud-Functions
[install_plugins] Installing plugin 'Cloud-Functions'
FAILED
Configuration error: open H:\.bluemix\plugins\config.json: The system cannot find the path specified.

[install_plugins] Checking status of plugin: container-registry
[install_plugins] Installing plugin 'container-registry'
FAILED
Configuration error: open H:\.bluemix\plugins\config.json: The system cannot find the path specified.

[install_plugins] Checking status of plugin: container-service
[install_plugins] Installing plugin 'container-service'
FAILED
Configuration error: open H:\.bluemix\plugins\config.json: The system cannot find the path specified.

[install_plugins] Checking status of plugin: dev
[install_plugins] Installing plugin 'dev'
FAILED
Configuration error: open H:\.bluemix\plugins\config.json: The system cannot find the path specified.

[install_plugins] Checking status of plugin: sdk-gen
[install_plugins] Installing plugin 'sdk-gen'
FAILED
Configuration error: open H:\.bluemix\plugins\config.json: The system cannot find the path specified.

[install_plugins] Running 'ibmcloud plugin list'...
FAILED
Configuration error: open H:\.bluemix\plugins\config.json: The system cannot find the path specified.

[install_plugins] Finished installing/updating plugins
Creating 'idt' script to act as shortcut to 'bx dev' command...
Out-File : Illegal characters in path.
At line:325 char:29
+   Write-Output $idt_batch | Out-File -Encoding ascii $idt_command
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

[install] Install finished.
[quit] --==[ Finished. Total time: 00:00:04 seconds ]==--

A system restart is required. Would you like to restart now (y/N)?:y




I reboot and then “Verify the installation”

Ibmcloud dev help
FAILED
Configuration error: open H:\.bluemix\plugins\config.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, insanely annoying!

Just run:

```
C:\Users\MyUser> $env:HOMEDRIVE="c:"
C:\Users\MyUser> $env:HOMEPATH="\Users\MyUser"
```

The run the IBM commands. You have to run the setting in each new console!

Comment: And still is on 3rd of December 2019

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and was able to fix it by setting env variable IBMCLOUD_HOME to the directory I installed ibm cloud cli to.

Answer (score 0):

Check the user home directory of your Win10 VM. IBM cloud CLI keeps some configuration files under `~/.bluemix`.

From the error message, `H:\` was treated as the user home, which seems abnormal since normally user home is not the root folder.